# Using Unity's uNet to create a turn-based RPG

Tags: networking, unity

I've been checking some tutorials about uNet and it seems pretty powerful. The NetworkManager is a great tool when you want to make generic games, but what is troubling me about it is the need of spawning a "Player". I intend to create a turn-based RPG, and for that, during the battle there's not a "physical player entity", there's two players which have a set of monsters and the players can select a monster to attack the opponents', but the player itself doesn't exist, in the end it sums up to a trade of commands between the clients. How can I achieve such an architecture with uNet? Should I discard the use of the default NetworkManager? Should I simply create a bodyless Player and go along with it?

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. I don't know uNet, I know [uLink](http://www.muchdifferent.com/), which needs all network entities to be stored inside a particular structure to be instantiated client, server and proxy sides. So, whether your point is either spawn a player or spawn different units for combat setup you could do it.